# Eclipse: no C/C++ option after installing CDT plugin

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse to program in Java and , having already familiar with this development environment , I would use it for C/C++ projects.

- Version: Eclipse SDK 4.2.2 (Juno)
- O.S.: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I installed the CDT plugin by following the italian guide of the ubuntu documentation:

http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Programmazione/Eclipse#CDT

The only difference is that, at point 4, I have not included the source shown (Galileo), but the my version (Juno)

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno

it's ok, found the source

- CDT Main Features
- CDT Optional Features

the installation is successful (indeed Eclipse show me CDT as the latest software installed, and an subsequent attempt to reinstall, Eclipse returns an error that it is already installed)

The problem is that when I restart Eclipse , I have no change. For instance , if I open the menu " File -> New -> Other" , I have no additional option to create a new C/C++ project.

I regularly installed on my computer the C/C++ compiler (gcc and g++ , version 4.6.3).

I also tried to install the plugin from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

no change.

I search through the options in Eclipse to see if it was a problem enabling views of items in the menu, but nothing. Even in the "Window -> Preferences" I have no "C/C++" category .
I also changed my workspace ..... nothing .

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue.  i installed the latest eclipse, luna and mars.  both had the c/c++ development tools.

my development environment had an older version of java installed, i.e. 1.6.  apparently, luna/mars require 1.7 to be installed.  i, at first, modified the eclipse.ini file to

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6

i started eclipse and the c/c++ project was not available.  so i couldn't create a c/c++ project because it wasn't available in the wizard.

i updated my java to 1.7 on my machine; changed the eclipse.ini file back

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7

then started eclipse.  viola.  the option to create a c/c++ project is now available.

so basically, it seems that the newer eclipse requires 1.7 java.  otherwise, it will disable features.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to open "C/C++ perspective". Try to go to menu "Window--Open Perspective -- Other--C/C++".

When you are in C/C++ perspective you should be able to create a new C/C++ project.

Also if you already have a loaded project, you can to convert to C++ project.  Simply select it and then follow the right-click menu: "New" -- "Convert to a C/C++ Project (Adds C/C++ Nature)". Alternatively, simply go to menu File--New--Convert to C/C++ Project and it will show the list of all projects.

But again, the first and major step is to switch to C/C++ perspective.

Good luck!